# How to use CURLU_ALLOW_SPACE with curl_easy_perform

Tags: libcurl

In the 7.78.0 release the CURLU_ALLOW_SPACE was introduced when rejecting spaces was made default; https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/7073.

Is it possible to allow spaces when using curl_easy_init/curl_easy_setopt/curl_easy_perform?

Comment: Could you explain with examples what you mean? How spaces allowness is expected to affect those functions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [create `CURLU` object](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_url.html) and set the URL by [`curl_url_set()`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_url_set.html) and then set your easy handle to use it by [`curl_easy_setopt()`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CURLU.html).

A small example:

```
CURLcode result;
CURL *easyp = curl_easy_init();
if (easyp == NULL)
  return error();

CURLU *urlp = curl_url();
if (urlp == NULL)
  return error();

if (curl_url_set(urlp, CURLUPART_URL,
                 "https://example.com/space path",
                 CURLU_ALLOW_SPACE) != CURLUE_OK)
  handle_error();
 
if (curl_easy_setopt(easyp, CURLOPT_CURLU, urlp) != CURLE_OK)
  handle_error();
 
result = curl_easy_perform(handle);
 
curl_url_cleanup(urlp);
curl_easy_cleanup(handle);

return result;
```

You may also want to use [`CURLU_PATH_AS_IS`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_url_set.html) option.